# What causes the 'Status: File Checked In/Out' message to display?

Tags: 2010

I'd like to prevent this message from showing up. Primarily the 'Checked In and Viewable' message. What causes these messages to show up?

Comment: On what page? I'm assuming Search Results, but please clarify on what page and where. Chances are it's produced thanks to an XSLT transformation that you can customise to let you omit whatever you want.

Comment: It's on a custom web part page.

Comment: Does the text show within web parts? If so, which kind? Content Query? Search Results? Both of these have XSL which you can edit.

Comment: plz add a screenshot with the error

Comment: screenshot: http://goo.gl/lf2oU

Comment: haw to remove status checked out and editable

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hiding the div in the master page, since in our case, we never wanted it to display.